# Append date to filename in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, append, rename, filenames

I want add the date next to a filename ("somefile.txt"). For example: somefile_25-11-2009.txt or somefile_25Nov2009.txt or anything to that effect

Maybe a script will do or some command in the terminal window. I'm using Linux(Ubuntu).

The script or command should update the filename to a new date everytime you want to save the file into a specific folder but still keeping the previous files. So there would be files like this in the folder eventually: filename_18Oct2009.txt , filename_9Nov2009.txt , filename_23Nov2009.txt

Comment: You may want yyyy-mm-dd instead of dd-mm-yyyy to get lexicographical sort of file names to also sort them chronologically.

Answer (score 105):

**Info/Summary**

With bash scripting you can enclose commands in back ticks or parantheses. This works great for labling files, the following wil create a file name with the date appended to it.

**Methods**

`Backticks -`

```
$ echo myfilename-"`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`"
```

`$(parantheses) -` :

```
$ echo myfilename-$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
```

**Example Usage:**

```
echo "Hello World" > "/tmp/hello-$(date +"%d-%m-%Y").txt"

(creates text file '/tmp/hello-28-09-2022.txt' with text inside of it)
```

Note, in Linux quotes are your friend, best practice to enclose the file name to prevent issues with spaces and such in variables.

Comment: This appends the date to the filename - in the example in the question the date needs to go *between* the file name and the extension.

Comment: This worked for me: `echo test > "data-csv-"\`date +"%Y-%m-%d"\`".txt"`

Comment: Or: `echo test > "data-csv-"\`date +"%Y-%m-%d.txt"\``

Comment: note that you have to remove the double quotes in "` (they are needed to bypass the SOF syntax interpreter to appear but they shall be removed in your commands)

Comment: It might not answer the full question, but it took me ages to find out to use backticks, so thank you.  (As @MehdiLAMRANI says, I use them without the double quotes.)

Comment: @CJB, nowadays, I'd probably prefer `$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")`.

Comment: @CJB I think you have the better way to do this! You beat me to the punch ,

Answer (score 53):

There's two problems here.

**1. Get the date as a string**

This is pretty easy.  Just use the `date` command with the `+` option.  We can use backticks to capture the value in a variable.

```
$ DATE=`date +%d-%m-%y`
```

You can change the date format by using different `%` options as detailed on the [date man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date).

**2. Split a file into name and extension.**

This is a bit trickier.  If we think they'll be only one `.` in the filename we can use `cut` with `.` as the delimiter.

```
$ NAME=`echo $FILE | cut -d. -f1
$ EXT=`echo $FILE | cut -d. -f2`
```

However, this won't work with multiple `.` in the file name.  If we're using `bash` - which you probably are - we can use some [bash magic that allows us to match patterns when we do variable expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ NAME=${FILE%.*}
$ EXT=${FILE#*.}
```

Putting them together we get:

```
$ FILE=somefile.txt             
$ NAME=${FILE%.*}
$ EXT=${FILE#*.} 
$ DATE=`date +%d-%m-%y`         
$ NEWFILE=${NAME}_${DATE}.${EXT}
$ echo $NEWFILE                 
somefile_25-11-09.txt
```

And if we're less worried about readability we do all the work on one line (with a different date format):

```
$ FILE=somefile.txt  
$ FILE=${FILE%.*}_`date +%d%b%y`.${FILE#*.}
$ echo $FILE                                 
somefile_25Nov09.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Dave but How or where do i run this script? Forgive me i'm new with Linux.

Comment: Can you give some more details on precisely what you want to do.  So you have a file in a directory which you want to date stamp in this way.  Is it just one file with the same name each time or could it be a number of files with a number of different name?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want to do.  It says the script should update the filename "everytime you want to save the file into a specific folder".  What is saving the file into the folder?  Where is it coming from?

Comment: If you want to have the filename changed everytime somebody saves something to a certain directory, then you'll need some filesystem monitor. Have a look at inotify (man inotify); you should be able to build something that way.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped

Answer (score 25):

```
cp somefile somefile_`date +%d%b%Y`
```

Comment: cp somefile somefile_$(date +%d%b%Y)     #prefered

Answer (score 14):

You can add date next to a filename invoking `date` command in *subshell*.

`date` command with *required  formatting options* invoked the braces of `$()` or between the backticks (`` `…` ``) is executed in a *subshell* and the output is then placed in the original command.

The `$(...)` is more preferred since in can be nested. So you can use command substitution inside another substitution.

Solutions for requests in questions

```
$ echo somefile_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
somefile_28-10-2021.txt

$ echo somefile_$(date +%d%b%Y).txt
somefile_28Oct2021.txt
```

The `date` command comes with many formatting options that allow you to customize the date output according to the requirement.

- **%D** – Display date in the format mm/dd/yy *(e.g. : 10/28/21)*
- **%Y** – Year *(e.g. : 2021)*
- **%m** – Month *(e.g. : 10)*
- **%B** – Month name in the full string format *(e.g. : October)*
- **%b** – Month name in the shortened string format *(e.g. : Oct)*
- **%d** – Day of month *(e.g. : 28)*
- **%j** – Day of year *(e.g. : 301)*
- **%u** – Day of the week *(e.g. : 4)*
- **%A** – Weekday in full string format *(e.g. : Thursday)*
- **%a** – Weekday in shortened format *(e.g. : Thu)*

Answer (score 6):

I use this script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date +"%b%d-%Y-%H%M%S")
FILE="$1"
name="${FILE%.*}"
ext="${FILE##*.}"

cp -v $FILE $name-$now.$ext
```

This script *copies* filename.ext to filename-date.ext, there is another that *moves* filename.ext to filename-date.ext, you can download them from [here](https://github.com/mlmateos/scripts).
Hope you find them useful!!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and I like the GitHub repo with the complete examples!

Answer (score 4):

I use it in raspberry pi, and the first answer doesn't work for me, maybe because I typed wrong or something? I don't know. So I combined the above answers and came up with this:

```
now=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
geany "OptionalName-${now}.txt"
```

That if you want to use geany or anything else

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

a bit more convoluted solution that fully matches your spec

```
echo `expr $FILENAME : '\(.*\)\.[^.]*'`_`date +%d-%m-%y`.`expr $FILENAME : '.*\.\([^.]*\)'`
```

where first 'expr' extracts file name without extension, second 'expr' extracts extension