# Adding timestamp to a filename with mv in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

Well, I'm a linux newbie, and I'm having an issue with a simple bash script.

I've got a program that adds to a log file while it's running. Over time that log file gets huge. I'd like to create a startup script which will rename and move the log file before each run, effectively creating separate log files for each run of the program. Here's what I've got so far:

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mDVuSZ5k)

```
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
mv server.log logs/$DATE.log
echo program
```

When run, I see this:

```
: command not found
program
```

When I cd to the logs directory and run dir, I see this:

```
201111211437\r.log\r
```

What's going on? I'm assuming there's some syntax issue I'm missing, but I can't seem to figure it out.

---

UPDATE: Thanks to shellter's comment below, I've found the problem to be due to the fact that I'm editing the .sh file in Notepad++ in windows, and then sending via ftp to the server, where I run the file via ssh. After running dos2unix on the file, it works.

New question: How can I save the file correctly in the first place, to avoid having to perform this fix every time I resend the file?

Comment: `\r` is carriage_return, examine your bash script, maybe is included inside the script

Comment: Where would that carriage return be coming from? I'm guessing that something about `logs/$DATE.log` is wrong, but typing `echo logs/$DATE.log` outputs the correct path.

Comment: how would i know? please attach the corresponded bash script, likely there is unnoticeable whitepspaces

Comment: Added a pastebin link to the main post, but that code snippet is literally the entire script, I've just substituted 'echo program' for the line that launches a java .jar

Comment: no idea ... seems to be correct, how about you try to append some strings after the `DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")`?

Comment: turn on shell debugging with `set -vx` just above your DATE=... cmd. Then you can see how variables are being expanded. If you're editing this file on Windows and then using the editor's ftp client to return the script to your unix/Linux environment, then you likely are getting DOS line-endings added to your script, i.e CR/LF. For *nix, you only want the LF. See if you can turn it off in your editor's setup. `dos2unix filename` on your *nix side will also fix this issue. Good luck.

Comment: I am using Windows to create the file, using Notepad++ then sending via FTP to the server and running via Putty SSH.

Comment: @AgentSnazz - When you use Notepad++, you need to set the line endings to Unix line endings. Select the menu _Edit->EOL Conversion->Unix Format_ when you edit a shell script. You can also look under _Settings->Preferences_ menu item. Under the _New Document/Default Directory_ tab. This will allow you to make sure all new files have Unix line endings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append date to filename in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1795678/608639), [Appending a current date from a variable to a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57590), [Adding timestamp to a filename with mv in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228047/608639), etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The few lines you posted from your script look okay to me. It's probably something a bit deeper.

You need to find which line is giving you this error. Add `set -xv` to the top of your script. This will print out the line number and the command that's being executed to *STDERR*. This will help you identify where in your script you're getting this particular error.

BTW, do you have a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of your script? When I see something like this, I normally expect its an issue with the Shebang. For example, if you had `#! /bin/bash` on top, but your bash interpreter is located in `/usr/bin/bash`, you'll see this error.

## EDIT

> New question: How can I save the file correctly in the first place, to avoid having to perform this fix every time I resend the file?

Two ways:

1. Select the *Edit->EOL Conversion->Unix Format* menu item when you edit a file. Once it has the correct line endings, Notepad++ will keep them.
2. To make sure all new files have the correct line endings, go to the *Settings->Preferences* menu item, and pull up the *Preferences* dialog box. Select the *New Document/Default Directory* tab. Under *New Document* and *Format*, select the *Unix* radio button. Click the *Close* button.

Comment: I'll see if I can try that. Running dos2unix once the file is ftp'd to my linux server solves the problem, but I'm looking for a way around that extra step. I don't have a shebang at the beginning, that may be the key.

Comment: @AgentSnazz - Ah ha! That's the problem. Unix shell scripts must have Unix line endings. Windows/MS-DOS uses carriage return-linefeed (aka CRLF or \r\n) to mark the end of the line. Unix uses just a linefeed (aka LF or \n). If you are editing a file for Unix on a Windows machine, you must use a program editor that can do the correct line endings (like [Vim](http://www.vim.org) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). **Do not ever use Notepad**. That's why you're seeing the `\r` in the file name. There's an invisible `\r` at the end of each line in your program.

Answer (score 114):

```
mv server.log logs/$(date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d%H%M").log
```

Comment: `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"` if your bash is a bit different

Comment: To stress @zinking's point, there must **not** be a space between the plus sign and the double quotes

Comment: I use `date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"` for a readable timestamp with seconds; it works fine on Linux with its colons in filenames.

Answer (score 11):

A single line method within bash works like this.

[some out put] >$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").ver

will create a file with a timestamp name with ver extension.
A working file listing snap shot to a date stamp file name as follows can show it working.

`find . -type f -exec ls -la {} \; | cut -d ' ' -f 6- >$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").ver`

Of course

`cat somefile.log > $(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").ver`

or even simpler

`ls > $(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").ver`

Answer (score 9):

I use this command for simple rotate a file:

```
mv output.log `date +%F`-output.log
```

In local folder I have `2019-09-25-output.log`

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's not a direct answer to your question, but there's a tool in GNU/Linux whose job is to rotate log files on regular basis, keeping old ones zipped up to a certain limit. It's `logrotate`

Comment: I'll look at that, I like my method because it nicely wraps up each run of the program in it's own log file.

Answer (score 5):

First, thanks for the answers above! They lead to my solution.

I added this alias to my .bashrc file:

```
alias now='date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S'
```

Now when I want to put a time stamp on a file such as a build log I can do this:

```
mvn clean install | tee build-$(now).log
```

and I get a file name like:

build-2021-02-04-03.12.12.log

Answer (score 1):

You can write your scripts in notepad but just make sure you convert them 
using this -> 
 $ sed -i 's/\r$//' yourscripthere

I use it all they time when I'm working in cygwin and it works. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$mv OldFileName NewFileName$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

Answer (score 0):

just use **lowercase** (for YEAR-month-day)  and **UPPERCASE** (for HOUR-MINUTE-SECOND) like

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%**Y**.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S") get **2023**.04.13-07.56.05
```

or

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%**y**.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S") get **23**.04.13-08.01.03
```