# Creating tar file and naming by current date

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a backup script in bash, to tar the contents of a folder and move the resulting file somewhere, but I don't really know how to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
name="$date +"%y-%m-%d""
tar -zcvf $name code
```

But the result is that the file is just named `+%y-%m-%d`. How can I change the script to name the file by the date as intended?

Intended output: `2013-08-29.tar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append date to filename in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1795678/608639), [Appending a current date from a variable to a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57590), [Adding timestamp to a filename with mv in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228047/608639), etc.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Like this:

```
name=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
tar -zcvf "$name.tar.gz" code
```

or even in one line:

```
tar -zcvf "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz" code
```

Drop `-z` flag if you want `.tar` instead of `.tar.gz`.

Use `%y` instead of `%Y` if you want just 2 digits of a year (`17` instead of `2017`).

`$()` is used for [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst).

Comment: Why not .tar.gz for the output file?

Comment: **Add date&time&timezone:** `tar -zcf "yourzipname_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S%z(%Z)').tar.gz" your_source_folder` will create zip including 24-hour format for example like `yourzipname_2021-01-25_21-29-14+0000(UTC).tar.gz`

Answer (score 10):

```
tar -zcvf "$(date '+%F').tar.gz" code-path
```

will produce full date; same as `%Y-%m-%d`. (see `man date` follow by `/`) to search and `%F`.

For example, it will generate:

```
2015-07-21.tar.gz
```

If `code-path` is a directory it will compress and archive all the files in it.

Answer (score 1):

On BSD System you may need to use it like this:

```
/usr/bin/tar -czvf /home/user/backup-`(date +%y-%m-%d)`.tar.gz /some/file.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

[root@node2rhel75:~]# tar -jcf /var/log/lvm_etc_backup-`(date +%F_%H-%M_%p)`.tar.bz2 /etc/lvm/; ls -lh /var/log/

tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     46 Jul 13 02:57 lvm_etc_backup-2021-07-13_02-57_AM.tar.bz2

[root@node2rhel75:~]#