# Unix shell, executing a command on a file based on date

Tags: linux, sh

I have an application server that produces daily log on the following format:

```
access_log.{Y-m-d}
```

So I want to execute a command in a way like this:

```
tail -f access_log.{+%Y-%m-%d}
```

Is there any way to do a in single line without creating variables ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating tar file and naming by current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498359/creating-tar-file-and-naming-by-current-date)

Answer (score 0):

Found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149753)

```
tail -f "access_log.$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
```