# Bash alias create file with current timestamp in filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to create a bash alias that will print the current UNIX timestamp every time the alias is called.  I have the following in my bash profile:

```
alias unix="echo "$(date +%s)""
```

However, it seems that the current unix timestamp is being stored as soon as the bash profile is sourced, and it doesn't change each time the alias is called.

For example, if I call the unix alias three times 10 seconds apart, the output is always the same. How can I create an alias that will evaluate the unix timestamp at the time the alias is called.  Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append date to filename in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1795678/608639), [Appending a current date from a variable to a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57590), [Adding timestamp to a filename with mv in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228047/608639), etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use single quotes to prevent immediate expansion.

```
alias unix='echo $(date +%s)'
```

Update: While I'm happy to have been able to explain the different expansion behavior between single and double quotes, please also see the other answer, by Robby Cornelissen, for a more efficient way to get the same result. The `echo` is unnecessary here since it only outputs what `date` already would output by itself. Therefore, `date` doesn't need to be run in a subshell.

Comment: Worked great thanks. It won't let me accept your answer for another 7 minutes, but I will.

Comment: Also, just for giggles, you could accomplish same with double quotes by escaping the $, which would also prevent immediate expansion: `alias unix="echo \$(date +%s)"`.

Comment: I could -1 for superfluous use of "echo", but I won't.  :)

Comment: Well, thanks for that. I was trying to explain why the asker's answer wasn't working, but I agree that it's not the most efficient way of getting the result. You could upvote the other, non-echo, answer below ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ alias unix="date +%s"
$ touch myfile.$(unix)
$ touch myfile.$(unix)
$ ls -l myfile*
-rw-r--r--  1 rbednark  wheel  0 Apr 11 21:46 myfile.1460436366
-rw-r--r--  1 rbednark  wheel  0 Apr 11 21:46 myfile.1460436368
```

Comment: +1 for a more elegant solution (though the OP's problem isn't explained).