# Creating filename_$(date %Y-%m-%d) from systemd bash inline script

Tags: linux, bash, date, inline, systemd

I am trying to execute a `systemd` timer and would like to keep the output from the executed script in a file per date. Here is my `ExecStart` script in the `.service` file:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo $(date +%Y-%m-%d) >> /home/username/test_output_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log'
```

This creates the file but adds a "hash" instead of the month name:

```
~/test_output_2017-ea3c0c2dd56c499a93412641e41008db-01.log
```

The content is the same:

```
2017-ea3c0c2dd56c499a93412641e41008db-01
```

If I run `/bin/bash -c 'echo $(date +%Y-%m-%d)'` in the shell without passing it through systemd service, it works as expected. Prints:
`2017-09-01`.

Does `%m` stand for something else than a month number in the `systemd` environment?

Any idea how to set the systemd service to put the standard output from the script into a file with the current date?
Expected result:
`test_output_2017-09-01.log`

Thank you.

Comment: did you tried  `\`date +%Y-%m-%d`\`  instead of  `$(date +%Y-%m-%d)` ?

Comment: `$(...)` evaluates the command. Otherwise, if we omit it, it will print `date +%Y-%m-%d` as a string and nothing more.

Comment: ` ... `  its like $(...) .. called command substitution => https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append date to filename in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1795678/608639), [Appending a current date from a variable to a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57590), [Adding timestamp to a filename with mv in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228047/608639), etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to escape the **$** and **%** signs, by doubling them both in order to make this work.

As described here:

- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2146
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines

> To pass a literal dollar sign, use "$$"

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo $$(date +%%Y-%%m-%%d) >> /home/username/test_output_$$(date +%%Y-%%m-%%d).log'
```